# How to wrap text after every n characters in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to wrap text in textarea after every n characters. I have tried with `cols` but it is allowing more characters. If it's not possible in HTML, I am new to javascript and jquery, Can we do this in javascript or jquery?

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="id" wrap="soft">
Hello
</textarea>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is this possible using other than textarea?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please at least give direction?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea *"The visible width of the text control, in **average character widths**"*.  The `cols=` attribute determines the *size* of the textarea, not how many characters it can fit.  I suggest you use `style="width:100px"` and replace 100 with an experimental amount to fit the number of characters you want along with a non-proportional font.

Comment: @freedomn-m so how can we fix for characters?

Comment: You also might like to review all of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=textarea+limit+characters+per+line